# SoapUI property transfer from previous Test Case and increment at the same time REST/JSON

Tags: json, rest, properties, soapui

I want to do this not using Groovy script but using regular Test Case, I'm transferring value from previous one and it looks so:

```
"extTransId":   "${Card / Charge / Magstripe (13001)#Request#$header.extTransId}",
```

Can I increment this value: `$header.extTransId` using something like `+1` or `++`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use the follow expression:

`"extTransId" : "${=${Card / Charge / Magstripe (13001)#Request#$header.extTransId} + 1}"`

Explanation:

In SOAPUI Request you can use the follow notation `${=}` to evaluate groovy code, so inside you use `${Card / Charge / Magstripe (13001)#Request#$header.extTransId}` to get the value of your previous request and then adds 1.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, amazing I spent some time watching tutorials, but missed such simple and useful thing.